# How to set the selectedKey property of a Nav component when there is a links property within a links property - Fabric React Nav

Tags: javascript, react-native, office-ui-fabric

I have just picked up React in general and followed some beginning tutorials, so excuse me my questions are stupid or the used code is just bad overall (don't hesitate to let me know), but after googling quite a bit I cant seem to find the answer for the following problem:

I am using Fabric React with a JS implementation (instead of TS). I successfully integrated my `Nav` component, by using the example I found here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/nav

Sadly this example misses the implementation of the `selected` events (make the selected item highlighted with a blue bar), the example just hard codes the selected item of the `Nav` component to key: key1:

```
selectedKey={'key1'}
```

After some research I found the perfect example of adding a selected event which changes the selection, which I found here: https://codepen.io/dzearing/pen/ZBGNQg?editors=0010

I rewrote it so I can use it in my JS file:

```
let navGroups = [
  {
    links: [
      {
        name: 'Home', 
        url: '#', 
        key: '#', 
        icon: 'HomeSolid', 
      },
      {
        key: '#recent',
        name: 'Recent',
        url: '#recent'
      },
      {
        key: '#photos',
        name: 'Photos',
        url: '#photos'
      },
      {
        name: 'Settings',
        url: '#',
        key: '#next', 
        links: [
          {
            name: 'Staff',
            url: '#',
            key: '#key2',
            icon: 'People'
          },
          {
            name: 'Restrictions',
            url: '#',
            key: '#key3',
            icon: 'Lock'
          }
        ],
        isExpanded: true,
        icon: 'Settings',
      },
    ]
  }
];

class NavBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._onClickHandler = this._onClickHandler.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      selectedNavKey: '#'
    }
  }

  render() {
    let { selectedNavKey } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="ms-Nav-LeftPane">
        <Nav
          selectedKey={ selectedNavKey }
          groups={ navGroups }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => {
      this.setState({ selectedNavKey: document.location.hash || '#' });
    })
  }

}
```

The selected event works fine for the regular buttons, but for some reason it doesn't work for the `Settings` nav item, which has it's own `Links` items. Any clue why this doesn't work for the `Settings` items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The problem was that I had the same values on the URL property which the selectedNavKey state uses:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => {
      this.setState({ selectedNavKey: document.location.hash || '#' });
    })
  }
```

The `Settings` navitem, and it's child's, all use the `#` in their `url` property, this caused the `selectedNavKey: document.location.hash || '#'` to not work properly. I never knew that the `document.location.hash` function uses the `url` but after reading the following it became much clearer:

[Hash-Based & Push-State URLs In React](http://singlepageapplication.com/react-app-url-schemes-part-1/)